# mysql_fetch_row() function show me warning

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i get `mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result`  here is my code

```
$query="select DISTINCT categories_memories.memory_id from categories_memories INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id=categories_memories.category_id";

$res=mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res))
{

}
```

please guide me

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169520/warning-when-using-mysql-fetch-assoc-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Your query failed so `mysql_query()` returned false which is not a valid MySQL result.

You need to have a look at the SQL error to fix it, here's a simple (but horrible) way to get the error in case one happens:

```
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL query supplies empty result set so mysql_fetch_row generate warning to avoid try below code

```
if($res){
   while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res))
   {
      do something
   }
}
```