# mysql_fetch_assoc() error

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning when using mysql_fetch_assoc in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169520/warning-when-using-mysql-fetch-assoc-in-php)

i am having a problem with the following codes, i am new in encountering this error
here is the code

```
session_start();
$uname=$_SESSION['login'];

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="sampledb";
$tbl_name="tblsched";
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblteacher WHERE teacherName=$uname";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$teacherid  = $row['teacherID'];
```

it gives me a "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean" error, how do i deal with this error?? i have used this code already a few times in other files and it worked perfectly except now, i checked the names of the rows and it was correct

i already tried using other commands such as mysql_fetch_array, mysql_result, mysql_fetch_row and it gives the same error

Comment: mysql_* functions should no longer be used :) Instead use mysqli_*

Comment: i am looking for sqli tutorials and can't find any...:)

Comment: Just type 'mysqli' in google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be using a variable that is a string, you need to encapsulate it in quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM tblteacher WHERE teacherName='$uname'
```

On that note, I see that it is coming from a Session variable, I take it that it is already cleansed to make sure there are no possible injection attacks within it - yes?

Comment: ohhh thank you for the help, didnt know i should add quotes to it

Comment: @PatrickNarcelles Anytime That's what we are here for right? :)

Comment: oh sir how can do i deal with dates??  $sql="SELECT SchedTimeTo FROM tblsched WHERE teacherID=$teacherid and SchedDateFrom<=$cd1 and SchedDateTo>=$cd1"; cd1 is the current date

Comment: Dates should be with `'`s same as the string. Thus your query should look: `$sql="SELECT SchedTimeTo FROM tblsched WHERE teacherID=$teacherid and SchedDateFrom<='$cd1' and SchedDateTo>='$cd1'";` If cd1 is the current date tho, just use mysql's function NOW() to speed up things.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius If the dates are in a datetime format already, I see nothing wrong at all with using the inbuilt functions (I would recommend it) :)

Comment: Well, I see nothing wrong either. It's just more work to have additional variable only for the query which contains current date but, obviously, in many cases this is not an option :)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblteacher WHERE teacherName='$uname'";
```

Comment: ohhh thank you for the help, didnt know i should add quotes to it

Comment: :-) that's OK - you have had few replies now

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblteacher WHERE teacherName=$uname";
```

change to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblteacher WHERE teacherName='$uname'";
```

the `uname` is string and it should be quoted using single or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This // user index no 

session_start();
$uname=$_SESSION['login'];

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="sampledb";
$tbl_name="tblsched";
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblteacher WHERE teacherName=$uname";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

**$teacherid  = $row[0];**
```